# Partial String Merge on Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes with varying information, but both dataframes have an account_number column that I was hoping to do a merge with.

The problem lies in this:

One of the dataframes has the full account numbers, for example `12345678` and the other dataframe has masked account numbers except for the last four digits so it would be like `****5678`.

I know for sure that all the last four digits are different for each account number, so how would I go about merging the dataframes together in an inner join if the last four digits match?

Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming these columns are in the string format, if they are not, please update your question to specify that.

If you are sure the last four digits will be unique, I would create a new column with the last four, and merge on that. This can be done by using [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html?highlight=map#pandas-series-map) and [lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions).

```
df1['last_four'] = df1['account_number'].map(lambda x: x[-4:])
df2['last_four'] = df2['account_number'].map(lambda x: x[-4:])
```

Comment: Thank you this works! The other column data was very irregular so I just made converted the entire dataframe into a string. Thanks